# Json status 404 error

Tags: xml, json, web-services

my json codes working well for another web services but my codes not working for this web site.
http://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?limit=30&offset=0&game=League+of+Legends&on_site=1

i get this web service from http://www.twitch.tv/directory/game/League%20of%20Legends.
i checked this source with FireBug it OK with 200. Whats wrong for that web service?

edit: my post method codes:

```
if (method == "POST") {
                HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
                int timeout1 = time;
                int timeout2 = time;
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters,
                        timeout1);
                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeout2);
                try {
                    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(
                            httpParameters);

                    httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));
                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                    StatusLine statusLine= httpResponse.getStatusLine();
                    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                    statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
                    System.out.println("#######"+statusCode);
                    if(statusCode!=200){
                        setError(ERRORS.UNKNOWN);
                        System.out.println("UNKNOWN error");
                    }
                    veri = httpEntity.getContent();


                } catch (final java.net.SocketTimeoutException e) {
                    setError(ERRORS.TIME_OUT);
                    System.out.println("TIME_OUT error");

                } catch (final java.net.UnknownHostException e) {
                    setError(ERRORS.UNKNOWN_HOST);
                    System.out.println("UNKNOWN_HOST error");

                } catch (final java.net.UnknownServiceException e) {
                    setError(ERRORS.UNKNOWNSERVICE);
                    System.out.println("UNKNOWN_SERVICE error");

                } catch (final java.net.ConnectException e) {
                    setError(ERRORS.CONNECT);
                    System.out.println("CONNECT error");

                }  finally {

                    if (httpPost != null) {

                        // httpPost.abort();
                        System.out.println("HttpPost found: ");
                    }
                }

            }
```

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: edited, codes added.

Comment: Is that web source giving you data from Riot Games API or is it scraping from the PvP.net client?